# How to remote debug a process which runs a package from NuGet in VS2012?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, nuget, remote-debugging

I have a solution with some projects referencing NuGet Ninject, Ninject.Extensions.Interception packages. In my case I want to remote debug some piece of code in Ninject.Extensions.Interception. I downloaded the source code for the release I'm using but when I go DEBUG->Attach to process... in Visual Studio it says that my breakpoints will never be hit.

How can I remote debug packages I installed through NuGet? I tried uninstalling all those Ninject packages with NuGet and referencing the Ninject.Extensions.Interception dll's I compiled manually but still doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you see any "pdb" files when you get the packages?  That's your bread and butter.

Comment: Yes, I can see the pdb files. How can I use them??